# How to concatenate the img src in asp.mvc aspx view page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

in asp.net mvc aspx page i am writing the html input image like this.

```
<img src="/public/images/"+<%: roleid %>+".jpg" alt="please load the image.." />
```

in above code roleid -1 is coming from db.but src not forming correctly.
**expected  result** src : /public/images/1.jpg but src not forming correctly.please tell me how to concatenate the string in aspx view engine?

thnaks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `roleid` is defined somewhere above in the View, you should form the attribute value in this manner:

```
src='<%: string.Format("/public/images/{0}.jpg", roleid) %>'
```

Things to note:

1. The quotation pattern: single quotes for the whole value, double quotes for strings in C# code.
2. Value string is generated within the `<%: %>` tag

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things i would like talk about.

1) Generating Image URL at runtime in View is not a good practice. You should Use ViewModel for that purpose like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public MyModel m;
  public void MyViewModel(MyModel m){this.m=m;}

  public string ActualIMageUrl
  {
    get
    {
       return "public/Images/"+m.RoleId+".jpg";
    }
  }
}
```

Now make your view strongly typed view of this ViewModel class instead of Model.

2)Dont directly use IMG tag in your View, Rather create new method for HtmlHelperClass using extenion method as follows,

```
public static class MVCExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string altText, string height)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", src);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttribute("height", height);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

Now in the View

```
@model MyViewModel
.
.
.
@Html.Image(Model.ActualImageUrl);
```

Hope it helped